# How to change background color of selected row in Vuetify Datatable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my Vuetify data table, I want to change the background color of the clicked row. In the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), i see that an event emitted named `click:row`, but it just returns the data of the row. How can detect the row field and change its css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the index of the clicked row in a data property:

```
data () {
    return {
      selectedRow: null
    }
}
```

And then apply a style conditionally. You'll need to use slots to do this, see the codepen below:

```
 <tr :class="key === selectedRow ? 'custom-highlight-row' : ''">
```

https://codepen.io/huntleth/pen/eYOrWog